# "Parental Control" app or setting for work

Tags: kiosk-mode, parental-control

I'm searching for an app or settings that will allow only 2 applications to be used on an android tablet.

They would use android and a web dashboard on chrome, on chrome they would get a certain link automatically loaded and I would try to make it impossible to go to other pages.

I want to only allow those two apps to be used.

I've looked in to kiosk mode ( but thats single app usage)
I've tried COSU but that also not a solution.
And parental control apps, but they show advertisement which I can't allow on the work floor.

Comment: So are we talking about two Android apps or two web pages in Chrome? Based on your description it is not clear what you want to restrict.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no such kind of application for parenting control for Android. There are a lot in different applications in Play Store but doesn’t seem anything akin to your requisite.

You can endeavor NORTON FAMILY PREMIER and check if that’s worth.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in the resources or references of the last answer but from my understanding their is literally hundreds of Applications on Google's Play Store that are All specifically targeted towards parental and elderly care..

These applications can assist you in doing many things, from identifying communication with a predator online to making sure your grandmother is still walking around the house at least once every so many hours...

Due to Android changes throughout it's evolution it is hard to say exactly what Application will work on your device..

Due to my research as an Android Enthusiast & Independent Developer, I have found that you are Most Definitely going down the path of Launchers..

The Launcher is the Very First application that runs on Android, If you use a specifically designed App Locker in conjunction with a Launcher... You will have the ability to perform a full device Lock Down, So-To-Speak.

Obviously you can find prebuilt Launchers Source Codes online, if you want to implement your own App Selection Screen within the device Launcher.

I hope this at least helps you find a correct solution on your endeavor.